# The antiforgery token could not be decrypted nopCommerce 4.40

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, nopcommerce, antiforgerytoken

Getting this error while open product detail page at front side of our nopCommerce 4.4 site.

from error there is no clue that error from which action and from which controller etc.

The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery
EventId: 7
SpanId: 390052c584d2844b
TraceId: d525f5d7ada43942af0e86d6ed879253
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 800074e6-1000-e800-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: (**Product detail page**)
ActionId: b7552ce7-1391-459c-a96d-ebf41d3f2d48
ActionName: Nop.Web.Controllers.ProductController.ProductDetails (Nop.Web)

An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.

Exception: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {20cdc418-c882-47e8-b3de-501029ea5ad5} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
```